# VB.NET: WPF Single Instance

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Has anyone using VB.NET 2010 been able to create a single instance application?
I've followed the MSDN sample but it does not have an Application.xaml file.

Converting any C# samples to VB doesn't work as I cannot override the Main sub in Application.xaml (C# calls it App.xaml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a Mutex.  In the projects properties, disable the application framework and set Sub Main as the startup object.  Then add a Module to your project:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module EntryPoint
    Sub Main()
        Dim noPreviousInstance As Boolean

        Using m As New Mutex(True, "Some Unique Identifier String", noPreviousInstance)
            If Not noPreviousInstance Then
                MessageBox.Show("Application is already started!")
            Else
                Dim mainWindow As New MainWindow()
                Dim app As New Application()
                app.Run(mainWindow)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

With this method, you will have to take care of your app's shutdown by calling the Shutdown method of the application.

Comment: This seems to work fine, but is is possible that application ressources found within the application.xaml are not longer available to the windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few possible solutions. I'd look through the whole thread here before deciding on one. Make sure you backup your code before trying any of these, so if one doesn't work, you can try another.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6c15b837-9149-4b07-8a25-3266949621a7/

Comment: Thanks for the link - I've already tried those. I'm after something a little more advanced...

Comment: To a certain extent, single-instance application is not possible in WPF, leaving little option but to MacGyver a workaround. What exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: The code from this Blog. The code can be downloaded at the bottom. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/11/21/customizing-windows-7-taskbar-from-wpf-part-2-jumplist-custom-actions.aspx